# DIY 4-Port Gbit and Wifi router

Tags: networking, router

I want to setup my own router.

My requirements are:

- Intel or AMD based
- Low power consumption
- min. 3x Gbit LAN + 1x GbitWAN Port
- Wifi (min. 802.11n)
- Optional: 4 SATA Ports for Backups

The hardware should be powerful enough to run an IPtables firewall, some smaller servers (XMPP, maybe Tor gateway, maybe VPN, small mail server, CUPS, ... but everything for only a few users)

The best would be probably something based on Intel Atom or on a mobile CPU. I already searched a bit and selected this hardware for now:

- ASRock D1800M (SoC with Intel Celeron J1800)
- 4GB RAM
- Intel PRO/1000 PT, 4x 1000Base-T
- Gigabyte GC-WB867D-I
- Available in Germany

Unfortunately, it's with 160€ a bit over budget, and I didn't include power supply and case yet. The main problem is, that I have to buy the network hardware seperately and I can't find a good board with at least the wired LAN integrated. Sure, there are options like Banana Pi R1/R2, but the reading in the community board isn't giving me so much trust and it's not x86 hardware. Supermicro has some board which satisfy most of my requirements, but as server hardware it is quite expensive.

So I guess, there are a few people out there who have similar expectations and their hardware already realized!

Comment: Is there any specific reason you don't want ARM-based hardware? They're generally cheaper and more power efficient at the small SoC end of the spectrum.

Comment: In many cases you only get outdated kernels. If there's a good support with modern kernels, it would be also okay. Unfortunately I only could find Banana Pi based on ARM and for R2 there's only very bad linux kernel support.

Comment: The Allwinner A20 in the Banana Pi R1 is supported by the armmp used in [Debian/armhf](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/armhf/ch02s01.html.en) though.